# How to remove whitespace from my website?

Tags: html, css, whitespace

This is my first big coding project and I'm unsure of what's causing whitespace at the bottom of the index/home page.

An example of the site can be seen at: http://2b2trust.org/index.html

Comment: Hey 2b2trust, welcome to stackoverflow. Be sure to post code-snippets of your project instead of links, because links can disappear but code on this platform won't.

Comment: Since you're using HTML/CSS/JS(?), you can use [Stack Snippets](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/358992/215552).

Comment: Hey sorry! Next time i will do that for sure

Comment: @2b2trust You can still [edit] your question. The purpose of Stack Overflow is to help people who have the same problem, not (just) the person asking. If you fix the problem, this question has no value at all. Please either update your question for future visitors or delete it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You are using a bootstrap template `Start Bootstrap - Clean Blog v5.0.2` the maker of this template added an `margin-bottom: 50px` to the `<header>` tag. if you change this tag to a other element like a `<div>` the problem is solved.

Comment: Glad it works! Good luck with your project. Be sure to mark this answer as "fix". When I looked at your project I saw some invalid code. This can make things really tough for you. You can validate your HTML for free if you use tools like this one: https://validator.w3.org/